# Запрос по поиску в mysql конкретного значения

Tags: php, mysql

*Сразу к примеру*: в одном из рядов столбца ***category*** есть значение [**7,10,17**] *(это id-номера категории для фильтрации при выборке, и они не повторяются, т.е. через запятую стоит id направления какой-либо организации)*, а в другой из этого же ***category*** может быть другое значение, например, [**7,1**]. Когда я делаю выборку с помощью оператора LIKE, мне нужно было найти из колонки ***category*** число **7**, вот здесь он находит ряды, в котором находится **7**, т.е. из вышеперечисленного примера число 17 тоже ищет.

Но мне нужен такой запрос, чтобы числа, стоящие через запятую, были как отдельные друг от друга числа для их конкретного поиска. Как организовать такой запрос?

Comment: Вам необходимо нормализовать таблицу. Для данной ситуации не существует иных простых решений, которые не имели бы рисков обвалиться в будущем.

Материалы по теме:

* [Нормализация отношений. Первая и вторая нормальные формы](http://habrahabr.ru/post/129195/)
* [Нормализация базы данных](http://www.softtime.ru/bookphp/gl12_6.php)
* [Нормализация реляционных баз данных](http://club.shelek.ru/viewart.php?id=177)

Comment: @tasimski, у нас решалось хранимкой, в цикле парсятся все значения и выполняются нужные проверки.

@Etki, иногда приходится заниматься денормализацией данных, но не в данном случае, я столкнулся с примерной задачей, когда увидел хранику, принимающую на вход 1 строковый параметр, в котором один id или через запятую несколько id, сначала все парсили и проиводили необходимые действия с каждым id.